# Python LIRC blocking Signal workaround not working

Tags: python, exception, signals, alarm, lirc

I've been having trouble with the **Python LIRC** function **lirc.nextcode()**. I turned off blocking, which allows the code **lirc.nextcode()** to be skipped if the **LIRC** queue is empty, by initializing with **lirc.init("program", blocking=False)** and tried **lirc.set_blocking(False, sockid)**. Neither worked and the code would always hang, waiting for a button press, when it should continue on.

I found this workaround that puts a time limit on **raw_input('prompt')**. So even if my **lirc.nextcodde()** waits for a button press, an alarm will go off after 5 seconds if no button has been pressed to deactivate the alarm, and skips the code anyway:

```
import signal

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=20):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = raw_input(prompt)
        signal.alarm(0)
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        print '\nPrompt timeout. Continuing...'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    return ''
```

Then changed it to fit my needs:

```
import signal
import lirc

sockid = lirc.init('weather', blocking=False)

class AlarmException(Exception):
    pass

def alarmHandler(signum, frame):
    raise AlarmException

def nonBlockingRawInput(prompt='', timeout=5):
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, alarmHandler)
    signal.alarm(timeout)
    try:
        text = lirc.nextcode()
        signal.alarm(0)
        print text
        return text
    except AlarmException:
        print '\nPrompt timeout. Continuing...'
    signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, signal.SIG_IGN)
    print 'timed out'
    return ''


nonBlockingRawInput()
```

***What I want to happen:*** If a button has been pressed and an IR code is in the **LIRC** queue, it should print the button that was pressed. If no button has been pressed and the **LIRC** queue is empty, it should print "Prompt timeout. Continuing..." and "timed out".

***What actually happens:*** If a button has been pressed and an IR code is in the **LIRC** queue it prints the button, but if no button has been pressed and the queue is empty it hangs until I close it.
It works exactly as intended until I change **text = raw_input(prompt)** to **text = lirc.nextcode()**, then it hangs on that function until it closes and gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/time.py", line 27, in <module>
    nonBlockingRawInput()
  File "/home/pi/time.py", line 16, in nonBlockingRawInput
    text = lirc.nextcode()
  File "/home/pi/time.py", line 10, in alarmHandler
    raise AlarmException
__main__.AlarmException
```

So not only does turning off blocking for **lirc.nextcode()** not work, but it also prevents the **Signal** alarm code workaround from continuing as well.

Here is a link "*[Python Lirc blocks code even when blocking is off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434500/python-lirc-blocks-code-even-when-blocking-is-off)*" to my original question regarding **LIRC** blocking, which is what this workaround was for. I'll gladly accept an answer for either.

Thanks ahead of time for any help, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switching to **Pylirc2** and using **pylirc.blocking(0)** fixed it.